# How on earth do i use Boost?

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2012, libraries

I'm reasonably new to C++, and I was going to mess around with threading for my Tamagochi game, however it seems that everything says I should get Boost for that.

So my question is, how on earth do I install it?

I've found ways of using it by doing the whole "Add the path in the properties" thing. And that works, however I'm guessing that if I use that way, I wont be able to compile and release it afterwards?

I also tried using BlueGo from vertexwahn.de.
but I have no idea what it actually does. I get the whole "It compiles the libraries for you" thing but, how do I use them then?
Should they work from within VS2012 without further tweaking, or do I still need to add in the path's in properties?

I just want to use the threading from Boost, and then build the project and send to a friend.

Comment: VS2012 supports `std::thread` you don't need boost for that

Comment: IMHO, you shouldn't try to use Boost under Windows on your own until you're seasoned with C++ and related concepts. Especially not to just get threading, while it's available in VS2012.

Comment: I'm a seasoned c# programmer, however I'm currently learning c++ as supplement for my class, and my teachers wishes us to use at least 2 libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some boost modules have to be built.

For Windows, you have to use bjam.exe to build your libraries.
And bootstrap.bat will build you bjam.exe

From your unzipped boost directory :

- bootstrap.bat
- bjam.exe release debug toolset=msvc address-model=32 --build-type=complete
- bjam.exe release debug toolset=msvc address-model=64 --build-type=complete

And check your stage/lib for *.lib, *.dll

(You may have to clean your stage/lib directory between two bjam commands)

Then, add include directory and library directory to your VS project.

Needed libraries will be automatically linked (you do not have to tell VS to use boost thread for example), boost use pragma to find out what is needed. It doesn't work for Linux though.

As previously stated, VS2012 already handle threads, but boost is much more than that and I strongly recommand using it for whatever you want to code.

With asio from boost, you can even make thread pool : see [recipe](http://think-async.com/Asio/Recipes)

Comment: I've gotten the things compiled, I found all the .dll and .lib files under the stage folder, but what I dont understand is;
How can i make sure it adds in the library when I compile it for release?

Comment: Release and Debug libraries have different names. When you compile for release, boost automagically give VS the good library name. If you really want to check it, you can always use [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on your generated application or library

Answer (score 6):

> I was going to mess around with threading...

If my reading of MSDN is correct, Visual Studio 2012 appears to support the new [threading features](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Threading_facilities) of [C++ 11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11). With this in mind, you don't need to install Boost. You can just use the standard [`<thread>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/hh920526.aspx) header instead.

Comment: `<future>`, `<condition_variable>` and `<mutex>` might prove useful too.

Comment: I know theres threading, but coulden seem to find any good documentation for it, so I figured I would try out boost. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 3):

1. download boost
2. compile boost (go to the boost directory, call
   bootstrap and after this is finished call b2)
3. decide which part of boost to use
4. add the main boost directory to your include path and the lib (with default it is in stage - just search for the lib files) directory to your linker path
5. make sure that you link boost thread dynamically (there may be problems if you link statically)
6. program

Comment: But with this way, will the library be added as well when I compile the code for release?

Comment: it depends on your settings in the release configuration. But of course, if you add it to the release configuration (include & lib path) it will be added to the code. Of course it's not as simple as that with the difference of h-only libraries, static libraries & dynamic libraries. In short - h-only and static linkage will be in your binary, dlls will remain seperate.